# How to convert dict to series (dtype: object)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dict in my hand. I need to convert this dict variable to series like reading csv file. How can I do this?

```
dict = {
 'confidentiality': 'complete', 
 'integrity': 'complete', 
 'access_complexity': 'high', 
 'availability': 'complete', 
 'authentication': 'none', 
 'cpe_type': 'application'
}
```

I try:

```
import pandas as pd
series = pd.Series(dict)
print(series)
```

My output:

```
access_complexity              high
authentication                 none
confidentiality                complete
cpe_type                       application
integrity                      complete
dtype: object
```

I want output:

```
0    complete
Name: confidentiality, Length: 1, dtype: object

0    complete
Name: integrity, Length: 1, dtype: object

0    high
Name: access_complexity, Length: 1048, dtype: object

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change variable `dict` to `d` because python code word and then iterate with `Series` constructor:

```
d = {
 'confidentiality': 'complete', 
 'integrity': 'complete', 
 'access_complexity': 'high', 
 'availability': 'complete', 
 'authentication': 'none', 
 'cpe_type': 'application'
}

for k, v in d.items():
    print (pd.Series([v], name=k))

0    complete
Name: confidentiality, dtype: object
0    complete
Name: integrity, dtype: object
0    high
Name: access_complexity, dtype: object
0    complete
Name: availability, dtype: object
0    none
Name: authentication, dtype: object
0    application
Name: cpe_type, dtype: object
```